# Bootstrap - change form group's css @media size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know I am doing this wrong but I have no idea how to fix it properly.

I have a sign up form that has a display: relative, on col-lg. But I did not know how to change a css based on a screen size. So I just duplicated the sign up form and gave it a different class name and changed the css accordingly.

Problem I came across was that if someone types information and then decides to adjust screen, all of there info disappears(because it is on the col-lg!)

How can I fix this issue without having to duplicate the form? I would like to not use jquery or javascript, but if I have to I will.

```css
.form-signup {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 70px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 35px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- First form -->
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 pull-right form-signup hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <form role="form">
                <h2>
                    <div class="text-center lead p-color">Tagline</div>
                </h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="FN" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="First Name" tabindex=1 autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="LN" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex=2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="EM" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex=3>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="PW" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Password" tabindex=4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input class="checkbox-focus" type="checkbox" tabindex=5>I agree to 
                            <a class="ri-anchor" href="#" tabindex=6>terms</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group register-div">
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex=7>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

<!-- Second Form -->
<div class="row row-offset center-block">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center hidden-lg"><img src="images/landing-md-xs.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt=" animation" style="height: auto; width: 500px;"/></div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 hidden-lg">
            <form role="form">
                <h2>
                    <div class="text-center lead p-color">TAGLINE</div>
                </h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="First Name" tabindex=1 autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex=2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Email Address" tabindex=3>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Password" tabindex=4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input class="checkbox-focus" type="checkbox" tabindex=5>I agree to 
                            <a class="ri-anchor" href="#" tabindex=6> terms</a>
                 </label>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group register-div">
                        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex=7>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that link, but I don't see how that answers my issue? did I miss a bootstrap css class that I can input? if so can you tell me what it is? thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-lg-x` is a bootstrap class that assigns your div grid size with the value of x. it's for large screen. but removing shouldn't drastically change the design like you have presented above. **It's because you have mis-linked bootstrap css file**. Also on the code above you have included *jquery* instead of *bootstrap*.

**Edit : for** Problem I came across was that if someone types information and then decides to adjust screen, all of there info disappears(because it is on the col-lg!)

For this add other classes `col-md-x`, col-xs-x` on the div as according to your need of x value.

Comment: How can I remove pull-right class when it goes to col-md-x?

Comment: I fixed the snippet to put bootstrap back into it

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up fixing this issue. I just changed the position to relative when it goes to a screen smaller than 1200px.